# How to convert a .net guid to oracle raw(16)

Tags: .net, oracle, guid, type-conversion

I have a problem!

My question is: **how to convert .net guid to oracle raw(16)?**

I tried it with:

```
select cast('9e953501-51d1-4701-e053-470f0c0a8ed5' as RAW(16)) from dual;
```

but it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a 32 char guid into a raw(16) column you can use HEXTORAW as in the example below:

```
 insert into MyCommands values 
    (  HEXTORAW('b7d394e722874e079f02b22c56ac88b1'),    
      'DeathMan',              
      'ReturnTrue'
     );
```

More (but not better) in :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions064.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `utl_raw.cast_to_raw`:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_raw('9e953501-51d1-4701-e053-470f0c0a8ed5') val
  from dual

                                     VAL
------------------------------------------------------------------------
39653935333530312D353164312D343730312D653035332D343730663063306138656435
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(replace('9e953501-51d1-4701-e053-470f0c0a8ed5','-') as RAW(16)) from dual;

select cast( translate('{9e953501-51d1-4701-e053-470f0c0a8ed5}','1234567890abcdef-{}','1234567890ABCDEF') as RAW(16)) from dual;
```